# Event tracking in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have two document in mongodb A and B. Field `code` from document A, contains value = **name(from document B)+id(from document A)**.  if somehow `name` is getting updated I want update field `code` from Document A automatically. I am using spring boot with mongodb. Kindly suggest how I can achieve this?

```
@Document
public class A{
private String id;
private String code;
....
}

@Document
public class B {
private String id;
private String name;
..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to represent the relationship between `A` and `B` through the use of the `code` field, use a service call in the application logic.

Create a query method to retrieve `A`s by the `name` part of `code`.

```
@Repository
public interface DocARepo extends MongoRepository<A, String> {
  List<A> findByCodeStartsWith(String code);
}
```

Create the service method for `A` that updates `code` with a new `name` part. The `DELIMITER` is necessary here to avoid a situation where you want to change `name` from 'car' to 'cars' but you also have some `B` with `name` of 'cart'.

```
@Service
public class DocAService {
  public final String DELIMITER = "::";

  @Autowired
  private DocARepo aRepo;

  public void updateNames(String prevName, String name) {
    List<A> aList = docARepo.findByCodeStartsWith(prevName + DELIMITER);
    for (A a : aList) {
      String code = a.setCode(name + DELIMITER + a.getId());
    }
    aRepo.save(aList);
  }
}
```

Create a listener on the `BeforeSaveEvent` to tap into the [Mongo Lifecycle events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

```
@Component
public class DocBBeforeSave extends AbstractMongoEventListener<B> {
  @Autowired
  private DocBRepo bRepo;
  @Autowired
  private DocAService aService;

  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<Person> event) {
    B b = event.getSource();
    if (b.getId() == null) return; // new doc

    B old = bRepo.findOne(b.getId());

    if (!Objects.equals(old.getName(), b.getName()))
      aService.updateNames(old.getName(), b.getName());
  }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `@DBRef` to create a relationship between `A` and `B`.

```
@Document
public class A {
  private String id;
  @DBRef
  @NotNull
  private B b;

  ...

  @Transient
  public String getCode() {
    return b.getName() + id;
  }
}
```

Now, the database will store a  reference to `B` in `A`, eagerly fetch `B` when `A` is retrieved, and `code` becomes a transient property of the `name` from `B`.

Comment: I can't make code as a transient as I need the track of that value( for tracking the values I am using Javers) also making service will not work for me because I need updation of `code` value when `name` in document `b` is changing.

Comment: the service call updates `name` in `B`, finds all `A`s using the previous `name`, and then updates `code`.  How is that different than what is being requested?

Comment: I want updation in `A` automatically something like if some event on `B` is triggered and value of name is changed the database should update `A` automatically.

Comment: Understood. Edited my answer to include how to tap into the Mongo lifecycle events, and changed the service to update all `A`s of a `name` part instead of updating the `B`, which can be handled elsewhere.